# How can I align correctly my div in mat design

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this list of component, I would like to align them on the same row. I kind of managed to do it , but they are not correctly aligned in vertical. Also, I do not know if I can replace that line

```
.search-container > * {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In angularjs I was using layout="row" but it doesn't exist in angular 4 anymore.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cteh6k

HTML

```
<div class="search-container" layout-align="space-between end">
    <div class="conditions">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select #fontSize value="28px" placeholder="Select Search Field">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let index of [1,2,3,4,5]" value="opt{{index}}">opt{{index}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Clearable input" [(ngModel)]="value">
            <button mat-button aria-label="Clear" *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button (click)="value=''">
                <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-form-field>      


    </div>
    <div class="buttons-container">
        <div class="condition-button clickable-elem">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="minus-circle-outline">asd</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="condition-button clickable-elem">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="plus-circle-outline">asd</mat-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-container">
        <button class="md-raised btn-submit" mat-button>FILTER</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.search-container > * {
    display: inline-block;
}

.search-container {
font-size: 0.7rem;

}
md-input-container .md-errors-spacer{
min-height: 0 !important;
}


.buttons {
  margin-left: 5px;

}
.condition-button {
  display: inline-block;

}
svg {
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;

}     
.conditions{
  max-height: 170px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following style

```
.search-container {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

P.S.: In case you want it to be center align use "align-items: center;"

Also remove this style

```
search-container > * {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See updated example [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cteh6k-jbbbpg?file=app/select-overview-example.css)

Answer (score 1):

add this css

```
.buttons-container, .conditions {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```